# Creating a simple form with formdata.php. Value is not displayed. Instead an empty page. How to fix it?

Tags: php, html, forms

i am new and learning to create a simple form using formdata.php. 
The problem is when I fill in password and click the imagebutton below in the form, I get an empty page.

What is wrong here?

This is the form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="formdata.php" method="GET" name="form">
<fieldset>
<legend>Put your bio</legend>
<p><label>type your name: <input type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="10"><label></p>
<p><label>type your pass: <input type="text" name="password" size="30" maxlength="10"><label></p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Common</legend>
<p>Do you like flowers?</p>
<p><label>Yes<input type="radio" name="time" value="yes" checked><label> <label>No<input type="radio" name="time" value="no"><label></p>
<p>what tools do you use to save time?</p>
<p> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="diary" checked>Diary</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chrono" disabled>Chrono</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="own">Own tools</label>
</fieldset>
<p>
<label for="sleep">how much time do you sleep?<label for="text">
</p>
<p>
<select name="sleep" size="5" multiple id="sleep">
<option>5</option> 
<option>6</option>
<option selected>7</option>
<option>8</option>
</select>
</p>
<p><label for="text">Share your experience:</label></p>
<p><textarea name="text" cols="30" rows="6" id="text">wow!</textarea></p>

<p><input type="reset" name="reset" value="clear"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></p>
<p><input type="image" img src="images/ibutton.png" name="imagebutton"></p>
<p><input type="button" name="button" value="oops"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the formdata.php:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['password'];

?>
```

Form.html and formdata.php are located in the same folder.
Denwer server is up and running, says it's ok.
The info in the browser looks like this:

C:/WebServers/home/html.loc/www/formdata.php? 
name=&password=12345&time=yes&diary=on&sleep=7&text=wow!&imagebutton.x=84&imagebutton.y=34

I should get "12345" on the page, but instead just an empty page.

Answer (score 2):

The URL displayed in your address bar

```
C:/WebServers/home/html.loc/www/formdata.php? name=&password=12345&time=yes&diary=on&sleep=7&text=wow!&imagebutton.x=84&imagebutton.y=34
```

proves that you are accessing the PHP file through your file system instead of accessing it through your web server.

You must access it with an URL like `http://localhost/form.html`
When the form is submitted, it will redirect to `http://localhost/formdata.php` and the webserver will process the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

You should access your site like `http://site.com/formdata.php?password=12345&...`
I think the reason is that when you are trying to open web page using it absolute address, browser uses file protocol and reads data from disk directly. Since this is not txt file and has open tag, it is treated like HTML and not displayed. If you don't know how to create virtual hosts, I can explain you.